# Health effect of electromagnetic and acoustic waves on brain function

Tags: biophysics

What if any effects are there on brain function from prolonged exposure to electromagnetic or acoustic stimulation?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! What research have you done before asking it here?

Comment: Nothing formal, just been thinking about some things I've been noticing

Comment: Homework questions are off-topic here unless you have shown an effort for an answer. Please show some research effort lest the question is likely to be closed.

Comment: The title is very uninformative. The title (which I now have edited) should not state whether you estimate the post will be interesting or not and stating that it is about biology carry no information as everything is about biology on Biology.SE.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blast_injury

Answer (score 4):

The question is extremely broad.

## Electro Magnetic signals

Even this subquestion is very broad. Electro magnetic signals encompass a lot of phenomenon, some of them represent health risks, some of them don't. It is funny to wish to limit the health effect to brain in your question as to reduce the scope of the question given how variable are difference electro magnetic waves can have on matter overall.

**Ionizing radiations**

[Ionizing radiations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ionizing_radiation) will obviously represent health risks. But even non-ionizing radiation can pose health risk.

**Non Ionizing radiations**

*Microwave*

You are probably aware that you should not put your cat in a microwave!

*Retina damage*

Intense light can cause photochemical damage to the retina. See [here](http://photobiology.info/Rozanowska.html).

*Intense infra-red*

High intensity infra-red affect cells (see [König et al. 1997](https://www.osapublishing.org/ol/abstract.cfm?uri=ol-22-2-135))

*Cell Phone*

Overall, there is likely no impact of cell phone radiation on our health. If there were any, it would be minimal.

See this Veritasium video: [Do Cell Phones Cause Brain Tumors?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wU5XkhUGzBs). You should also have a look at the skeptics.SE post [Do mobile phones have anything to do with brain cancer?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/569/do-mobile-phones-have-anything-to-do-with-brain-cancer).

*Cell phone towers*

Likely has no health effect. See [Do cellphone towers cause health issues?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/20001/do-cellphone-towers-cause-health-issues)

*Other electro magnetic signals*

For more information, you should have a look at [WHO > Electromagnetic fields and public health: radars and human health](http://www.who.int/peh-emf/publications/facts/fs226/en/)

## Sound wave

Some sound can cause hearing loss. The frequency of this sound, the intensity and duration of exposure to the sound are all important in determining the degree of the hearing loss. Have a look at [this article from the American Hearing Society](http://american-hearing.org/disorders/noise-induced-hearing-loss/) for more information.

Comment: Please add about sound waves as OP is asking about it too.